# Date showing is wrong

Tags: java, date

I use this method to generate my today date to write it to file.

```
    public void DateFiledControl() {
    Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/DD");
    String strDate = myFormat.format(currentTime.getTime());
    System.out.println(strDate);
}
```

But , my result is : `2013/03/63`

Why?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you should be using `dd` instead of `DD`, which [the `SimpleDateFormat` documentation makes fairly clear.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Also, be aware that 'MM' is the month, but 'mm' is the minutes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
```